# Implementing BFS on same level vertexes of a graph data structure

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to understand  graphs in data structures and got struck here in understanding. can anyone help in understanding this approach. Graphs allow multiple vertexes to connect to any arbitrary vertex without any constraints. while inserting edges, it is possible the vertex to be connected may be on the same level or at any below levels.

[image: BFS With different vertexes]

In the above figure, BFS through graphs gives 5,6,7 in one and 5,7,6 in another. There is no constraint to get the same level vertexes on graph. How is this identified?

Please let me know as none of the resources point that differenece. Both 6,7 are unvisited from 5,if one refers to 7 and adds to queue(image-1). BFS will be violated.

**EDIT:**

[image: BFS Graph Image]

In the above BFS Example image we have 5 vertexes and if we start from 5 we can either traverse to 6,7 as adjacent nodes. if we are trying to implement BFS here then we can either add 6 or 7 to queue but 7 is the valid one as it is at the same level. How is this identified?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "nodes at the same level". In the last example the nodes 6 and 7 are in the same level (they are 1 edge far from node 5), even more, node 8 is also at the same level than 6 and 7

Comment: Ok,BFS means traverse through breadth and then go to next line. From 5, It is also possible to consider 7( assume the graph is inverted now). and all these approaches are considered correct( BFS- 5,7,8,9,6 (or) 5,7,8,6,9 (or) 5,7,6,8,9 (or) 5,7,6,9,8)?. Then how do we differentiate between BFS and DFS?

Comment: I believe in any of the graph you put in the questions 5,7,8,9,6 is not a valid BFS

Comment: BFS gives you the nodes in level order, that means that if you arrive (in that order) to a node with level `k` all the next nodes would be in levels `k` or upper. In the order: 5,7,8,9,6 you can't have node 9 before node 6. Because node 9 is 2 edges far away from the root (node 5) while node 6 is 1 edge far away

Comment: As a matter of fact, the two graph in the last image represents the same graph. Rotating the image representation will not change the graph. A graph is defined by two sets: A set V representing the vertex, and a set E (which is a set of subsets of V with carnality equals 2).

Comment: Ok can you spot the BFS and DFS for the same graph ?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado- 5,7,6,9,8 is also invalid BFS ?

Comment: No, 5,7,6,9,8 is not a valid BFS combination either. For example a valid BFS could be 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9. In general (for this graph) a BFS combination is (5) (6,7,8) (9) where any number inside a parenthesis can be switched with any other number inside the same parenthesis.

Comment: A valid DFS combination would be: 5, 6, 9, 8, 7

Comment: To generate a DFS order you use a [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). And to generate a BFS order you need to cover the graph by levels, and by levels I mean: first the root, then the root children's, then the children of the root children's, and so on. For this you use a Queue, you can look how it works on [wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjAyPiz653sAhWjUt8KHWHZBm4QFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBreadth-first_search&usg=AOvVaw0lzSwCjCSztMoEyL4XHC8J)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two drawings you posted show identical graphs: the same three vertices are connected with the same three edges. Graphs don't have levels. They don't keep track of any type of edge ordering, nor the horizontal or vertical layout of the vertices when the graph is drawn.

A BFS starting from vertex 5 could visit either 6 or 7 next. Either order is a valid BFS traversal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i'm not sure if i understood correctly here. BFS is supposed to traverse through the breadth and if it chooses the vertex below (This might be violated). I have edited the question too. Can you please provide more explaination on this.